# How to get_children and their grand children

Tags: wordpress

How to get grand-childrens of children of a page?

```
<?php
global $post;
$pages = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'numberposts' => -1
));

if ( $pages ):
    $rows = array_chunk( $pages, ceil( count($pages) / 3 ) ); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ( $rows as $row ): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <?php foreach ( $row as $city ): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= get_permalink( $city ) ?>"><?= $city->post_title ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
```

by using wp_list_pages I can't make columns for my list

Comment: Check this out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247858/wp-list-pages-change-output-of-hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Shows children page links on both parent and child pages.

```
<?php
    global $post;
   // Use parent page if exists, else use current page    
    $child_of_value = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );
    // Depth of 2 if parent page, else depth of 1
    $depth_value = ( $post->post_parent ? 2 : 1 );
    // Build argument array
    $wp_list_pages_args = array( 
        'child_of' => $child_of_value,
        'depth' => $depth_value,
        'title_li' => 'Sections',
        'echo' => 0
    );
    // Now, output the result
    wp_list_pages( $wp_list_pages_args );

?>
```

Comment: But how to add in main page children and grandchildrens pages?

Comment: get your main page id by using $post->ID and pass into $post->post_parent : $post->ID